# White Labeling a TideSDK App

Tags: tidesdk, white-labelling

I'm in the process of building out my first TideSDK app by transitioning an existing AIR app and the client would like to white label the app. For the AIR app, we could point the `application.xml` file to the location of brand-specific HTML, but I don't see an obvious way to do that with `tiapp.xml`. Is it there and I'm just missing it?

In this case, white labeling mostly means a logo change and perhaps a few colors, so it's hardly anything intensive. What's the best way to do something like this using TideSDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TideSDK is no different than any web app for branding. CSS is used to style your HTML. Any default CSS you have in your base app may be overridden for branding of course.

Beyond the HTML, the native UI is controlled by the OS, and you have only the icon to be concerned with and replacing the default artwork (with your own branding) in the native installer we provide.

If you need to change the icon name, which is not a necessity, do this in the tiapp.xml and manifest. Just replace the image with one of your own. The same applies to the installer art.

Answer (score 1):

U can modify the logo with the attribute image in manifest file:

#image:default_app_logo.png

change to

#image:my_logo.png

Comment: Thanks, Mital. We're not talking about the app icon here, but rather about the logo that appears on various screens. Does this still apply?

Comment: Follow up question for you: In the CLI build script (`tidebuilder.py`), there's a `--assets` flag, but I can't find a clear explanation of how that might be used. Could it be useful for something like this?

Comment: I don't think --assets is being used here. all you want is just modify your application manifest with you required logo.